# pytorch split array by list of indices

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, numpy-slicing

I want to split a torch array by a list of indices.

For example say my input array is `torch.arange(20)`

```
tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
        18, 19])
```

and my list of indices is `splits = [1,2,5,10]`

Then my result would be:

```
(tensor([0]),
 tensor([1, 2]),
 tensor([3, 4, 5, 6, 7]),
 tensor([ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]))
```

assume my input array is always long enough to bigger than the sum of my list of indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`tensor_split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tensor_split.html) on the cumulated sum of the `splits` (e.g. with [`np.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html)), excluding the last chunk:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

t = torch.arange(20)
splits = [1,2,5,10]

t.tensor_split(np.cumsum(splits).tolist())[:-1]
```

Output:

```
(tensor([0]),
 tensor([1, 2]),
 tensor([3, 4, 5, 6, 7]),
 tensor([ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible option would be to *slice* the tensor first, then [`split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.split.html) it :

```
import torch

t = torch.arange(20)

splits = [1, 2, 5, 10]

out = torch.split(t[: sum(splits)], splits)
```

Output :

```
(tensor([0]),
 tensor([1, 2]),
 tensor([3, 4, 5, 6, 7]),
 tensor([ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used numpy for my example but it might work with tensors as well.

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
        18, 19])

def split(array, split_list: list[int]):
    if sum(split_list) > len(array):
        return None
    tup = ()
    for i in split_list:
        tup = tup + (array[:i].tolist(),)
        array = array[i:]
    return tup

print(split(array, [1, 2, 5]))
```

And i got this as output:

```
([0], [1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

I hope this is what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using PyTorch's torch.split function along with list comprehension to split the array according to the provided indices.

```
import torch

input_array = torch.arange(20)
splits = [1, 2, 5, 10]

result = [input_array.split(split) for split in splits]
print(tuple(result))
```